# How to create identity matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How do I create an identity *matrix* with numpy?
Is there a simpler syntax than

```
numpy.matrix(numpy.identity(n))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simpler syntax:

```
np.matlib.identity(n)
```

And here's an even simpler syntax that runs much faster:

```
In [1]: n = 1000
In [2]: timeit np.matlib.identity(n)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.78 ms per loop
In [3]: timeit np.matlib.eye(n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 695 us per loop
```

Comment: do you need to use `matlib`? you can't just do `np.eye(n)`? `matlib` specifically produces matrices, as opposed to "normal" numpy functions which produce numpy arrays.

Comment: According to the documentation, it seems that np.eye doesn't necessarily create square matrices. As for the performance gain using np.matlib.eye, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11):

Also [np.eye](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) can be used to create an identity array (In).

For example,

```
>>> np.eye(2, dtype=int)
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
>>> np.eye(3, k=1)
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a *simpler* solution.  You can do it slightly *more efficiently*, though:

```
numpy.matrix(numpy.identity(n), copy=False)
```

This avoids unnecessarily copying the data.

Comment: i have never used `np.identity`, always used eye .. do you know what is the difference between `np.eye` and this one?

Comment: @wim: No difference.  `numpy.eye()` is a bit more flexible.  NumPy's interface isn't very streamlined, and many functions with overlapping functionality exist.

Comment: @wim: according to the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) `np.eye` is like `np.identity` but with added functionality. You can specify the column size and shift the diagonal over.