# How do I form a matrix identity?

Tags: python, list, matrix, range, identity

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to generate a matrix of size **n x n**. Whatever the matrix is, I have to fill in the number `1` from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner and `0` everywhere else.

```
def identity(m):
    new_identity = []
    old_identity = m
        for i in range(len(old_identity)):
            new_identity.append(old_list[1])
    return new_identity
```

For example, if the matrix was 3 then the expected result would be:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Or to make it easier to visualize:

```
[[1, 0, 0],

 [0, 1, 0],

 [0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: possible solutions with numpy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935629/how-to-create-identity-matrix-with-numpy)

Comment: @Bill, that question deals with comparison, not creation.

Comment: oneliner no numpy: `ones = [[0]*i + [1] + [0]*(n-i-1) for i in range(n) ]`

Answer (score 7):

where `n` is the size of the identity to make

```
def identity(n):
    return [[1 if i==j else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one might not be the most pythonic, but it's faster than the other solution.

```
def identity(m):
    result = []
    for i in range(m):
        row = [0]*m
        row[i] = 1
        result.append(row)
    return result
```

On my machine, for a 500x500 matrix, my function takes 3.13 ms to execute, while the python list comprehension solution (that makes m² comparisons) takes 47.48 ms to complete.

Of course, you should use `xrange` instead of `range` if you're using python 2.x